# react-table not rendering rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

react-table does not show data in rows.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "../../custom.css";
import {COLUMNS} from './columns';
import { useTable } from "react-table";

//some code

const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])

  const data = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(childrens);
    return childrens;
  }, [childrens])

const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    footerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  })

//and more code here 

<table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            console.log(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
          ))}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

For debugging, I have console logged the output of each row and there is all the data, there is also an initial data array in the console and everything is also correct there.

[image]

Comment: It's very strange that all the values are undefined while the original are not. Could there be an issue when you translate the data?

Comment: could you please make sure that you are mapping the data to the translated variable name which should be present in the data. In the original I could see the surname, do you also have Фамилия attribute in the original object?